# How to join multi lines if pattern matches within multi segment

Tags: perl, awk, sed, string-matching

My file contains:

```
segment  
bob is working  
linda is studying  
john is reading  
+b eating  
+b drinking  
+j listening  
segment  
john is driving  
linda is cooking  
bob is sleeping  
+b snoring  
+l washing  
segment
```

I want to process the file with something like `sed`, `awk`, or anything to become:

```
segment  
bob is working eating drinking  
linda is studying  
john is reading listening  
segment  
john is driving  
linda is cooking washing  
bob is sleeping snoring  
segment
```

I have tried:

```
sed 'N;s/\n\s*+b//;P;D' file
```

However, only the lines with `+b` processed

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
$0 == "segment" {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        print line[key]
    }
    print
    numKeys = 0
    next
}
/^[+]/ {
    key = substr($0,2,1)
    line[key] = line[key] OFS $2
    next
}
{
    key = substr($0,1,1)
    line[key] = $0
    keys[++numKeys] = key
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
segment
bob is working eating drinking
linda is studying
john is reading listening
segment
john is driving
linda is cooking washing
bob is sleeping snoring
segment
```

Comment: Excellent solution! BTW your script coincidentally starts with removing extra whitespaces in the end of lines as mine.

Comment: great solution Ed Morton, it really works! appreciate if you could explain a little bit on the function used in this awk script, quite new with substr call

Comment: @WalitGemilang you're welcome. The man page describes better than I could what substr() does, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is your option, please try the following:

```
perl -ne '
    s/\s+$//;
    if (/^segment/) {
        push(@ary, $_);
        print(join("\n", @ary), "\n");
        undef @ary;
    } elsif (/^(\S)\S*\s+is/) {
        push(@ary, $_);
        $index{$1} = $#ary;
    } elsif (/^\+(\S)\s+(\S+)/) {
        $ary[$index{$1}] .= " $2";
    }
' file.txt
```

output:

```
segment
bob is working eating drinking
linda is studying
john is reading listening
segment
john is driving
linda is cooking washing
bob is sleeping snoring
segment
```

- `-n` option tells `perl` to iterate over the input file as `awk -n`.
- `s/\s+$//` removes trailing newline character(s) and whitespace(s) if any.
- The `if (/^segment/)` portion flushes the contents in `@ary` and
  reset the array for the next segment.
- The next `elsif (/^(\S)\S*\s+is/)` portion matches with the line
  like `bob is working` then add the line into `@ary` by memorizing the
  index of the arrary with the initial like "b".
- The next `elsif (/^\+(\S)\s+(\S+)/)` portion matches with the line
  like `+b eating` then add the action `eating` to the element of `@ary`
  indexed via "b".

I could write a script with `awk` as well but the script would be
longer. I prefer `perl` for its flexibility (and the weirdness).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the shortest but here's a straightforward sed version:

```
sed <file -E '
    :l;
    /(^|\n)segment[ \t]*$/!{
        N;
        s/(^|\n)(.)([^\n]*)[ \t](.*)\n[+]\2[ \t]+([^\n]*)/\1\2\3\5\4/;
        bl;
    }
'
```

- if not match segment line,

  - append next line to pattern space
  - search for lines starting with x and +x and append tail of latter to former
  - jump back to top
- otherwise, implicit print, delete pattern space and start next cycle